# issue with fields_for, _attributes missing in NEW action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did something wrong or there's an issue with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or `fields_for`

I use rails 3.0.3.

I've 2 models

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end
```

In my `_form.html.haml`

```
= f.fields_for :address do |a|
  = a.label :street, t("activerecord.attributes.address.street", :default => 'Street'), :class => :label
  = a.text_field :street, :class => 'text_field'
```

When I GET `/customers/new` the HTML source code for the street input field is

```
<input class="text_field" id="customer_address_street" name="customer[address][street]" size="30" type="text">
```

When I GET `/customers/1/edit` the HTML source code for the street input field is

```
<input class="text_field" id="customer_address_attributes_street" name="customer[address_attributes][street]" size="30" type="text" value="...">
```

The EDIT is correct and works fine, but the NEW is wrong, the `_attributes` is missing in the ID and NAME.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake

in the `new.html.haml` I got

```
= form_for :customer, :url => customers_path, :html => { :class => :form } do |f|
```

to make it works I've to replace `:customer` by `@customer`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!